# Is this a permutation matrix?

Tags: matrix, operators, permutation, linear-algebra, shift

[Matrix(Image Courtesy:Y. Liu et al.: Graph Learning Based on Spatiotemporal Smoothness for Time-Varying Graph Signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4qCS.png)

Is this matrix a permutation matrix with 0s on the diagonal and 1s above the diagonal. Does that mean the blank parts are all filled with zeroes? Please advise on this

I would want to get a confirmation on my description of the matrix

Answer (score 0):

The first column is entirely filled with zeros. It is therefore not invertible and cannot be a permutation matrix. A permutation matrix has exactly one <s>zero</s> one in every row and column.

Yes the blank parts are usually assumed to be 0 unless they are surrounded from *every* side by ellipses (...) between some other values. So in this case the matrix `B` should have `M-1` entries of `1`, just to the right/above of the diagonal.

The matrix is actually a [Shift Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix). If applied to a vector it moves every entry  by 1 in the same direction and drops (zeros out) one entry at the end. So You were not that far off with permutation.

**EDIT**: I made a big mistake in my 3rd sentence. A permutation matrix has `M-1` zeros and one `1` in every row and column not the other way around.